# Why can the error function be written in two ways?

Tags: statistics, computational-mathematics, error-function

I have read that the error function can be written as

$$erf(x) = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\cdot\int_{0}^{x}{e^{-t^2}}~\mathrm{d}t$$

and

$$erf(x) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\cdot\int_{-x}^{x}{e^{-t^2}}~\mathrm{d}t$$

and they mean the same thing. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Integral of even function is symmetric about the origin

Comment: Quite easy. By symmetry, we have the factor $2$, if we only go from $0$ to $x$.

Comment: So if it was 1/sqrt(pi), would it be that it is symmetrical about the origin?

Answer (score 4):

It should be obvious that the shaded area on the left is half the shaded area on the right:
[image]